# Rails 3.0 form_tag Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've used the following code in rails 2.3 without having to have a named route:

```
 <% form_tag :controller => :session, :action => :login do %>

<ul>
    <li><%= label_tag :email %><%= text_field_tag :email %></li>
    <li><%= label_tag :password %><%= password_field_tag :password %></li>
    <li><%= submit_tag 'Sign In', :id => 'login_submit' %></li>
</ul>

 <% end %>
```

However, I'm converting my app to a 3.0 app and I get an error message saying "No route matches "/session/login"."

Do I need to create a named route in rails 3.0 or is there a better way to do this?

Creating a named route doesn't seem like the right approach because people would be able to call that through the url.

Comment: Please provide route details.

Comment: The routes I have so far, or the error message?

Comment: @Brian Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: +1 for saying thank you in your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add resources route for sessions:

```
resoures :sessions
```

and fix form:

```
 = form_tag sessions_path do
   ...
```

Remember rename you login action in sessions controller to new

**UPD:**

or you can add named route for 'session/login'

```
match 'session/login' => 'session#login', :as => :new_session
```

and use:

```
= form_tag new_session_path do
```

Comment: so maybe something like resources :session, :only => [:new]

Comment: The problem I see is that someone would be able to type in the url somesite/sessions/new

Comment: Alright, sounds good. I guess I'll just create a before_filter to prevent people from trying to create new sessions while already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

A named route is not necessary, but you should declare something like this in your routes file:

```
match "/sessions/login" => "sessions#login"
```

In RoR 3, "sessions#login" is a short hand for *"the login action of the sessions controller"*.

The [official RoR guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) on routes is very well written and should help you a lot.